# different php script speed between local and production server

Tags: php

I would know how to identify what is this problem.
On my local server, the php script works perfectly and the speed is the same  for the catalog and the administration.

If I use the same site on my production server, it's not the same problem.
The catalog works fine, no problem
The administration, the page is loaded is between 6s until 17s. I do not understand why it's so long.

production server

```
time : 11.7s
Event   When    How long    Sum
Redirect    0   0   0
DNS 7   2   2
Connect 9   94  96
Request 103 10096   10192
Response    10199   10  10202
DOM 10220   1503    11705
Interactive 11151   0   -
Content loaded  11152   125 -
Load event  11727   2   11707


local server : 2.38
Event   When    How long    Sum
Redirect    0   0   0
DNS 12  0   0
Connect 12  0   0
Request 12  924 924
Response    936 4   928
DOM 948 1424    2352
Interactive 1813    0   -
Content loaded  1814    129 -
Load event  2376    4   2356
```

Comment: Is your production server far from you ?

Comment: Without detailed information about your server architecture and the script you're running, all we can do is guess.

Comment: The problem is the same is I am in north America or in Europe. The server is in Europe

Comment: Does the application need to query a database? Is the database server local to the production server? Accessing a database over the network can be slow, although 10+ seconds seems out of line unless your retrieving lots of data.

Comment: The application has low data, the DB and application on the same server.